# Anylogic - Seize resource based on agent location

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I'm a novice AnyLogic user and I am wondering whether it is possible to seize a resource from a resource pool, based on the seizing agent's location. So if the agent is located in node1 it will seize resource1 otherwise it will seize resource2? If it is, what code can I use?

I have tried using the "Customize resource choice" and "Resource choice condition", but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is in fact a very simple way. The resource pool field is a dynamic one. Clicking on the equal symbol in the service properties turns the equal symbol to a circular arrow which means this field is dynamic and can thus be defined based on agent properties dynamically.

[image]

Now, in this field you can enter your code. The code here is not your regular code, so you should not use "if", use the following syntax instead:

```
<statement> ? <value if true> : <value if false>
```

Finally, to refer to the agent, you just need to use the word agent. Here is an example with three resource pools:

```
node1.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool1 : node2.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool2 : ResourcePool3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! - So should the code be written like this for three resource pools?          

? : node1.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool1 : node2.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool2 : node3.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool3

Comment: Not exactly, because you always need an "else" condition which will assign a resource pool if none of the conditions are true. So for 3 resource pools, you should use my code:
node1.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool1 : node2.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool2 : ResourcePool3

Comment: Alternatively, add a resource pool if none of the conditions are true like that:

node1.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool1 : node2.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool2 : node3.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool3 : ResourcePool 4

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it also possible to use an AND statement in some way - I don't know the syntax. But for example: node1.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool1 AND node2.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool1 : node2.contains(agent) ? ResourcePool2 : ResourcePool 3. So that if the agent is inside two different notes a specific resource pool is seized.

Comment: Syntax is && although your logic in the comment doesn't make a lot of sense. I recommend you go over Java basics in AnyLogic help.

Comment: Meanwhile if the answer works for your question, please accept it as a solution or mark it as useful.